# Checking whether a "string" expression in a specified variable is contained in several other variables

Tags: string, r

This is a very basic question... and I'm sure its written here somewhere... I'm trying to create a new variable that tells me whether there is a mendialian violation in a trio (genetics data)

For example (for those who don't know genetics):
For one family (one per row), I have Father, Mother and Childs genotype represented as A/G, G/A, G/G (as separate variables).  I want to create a new 0/1 or False/True variable that tells me whether Allele 1 of the the Child is seen in either allele of the mothers genotype or in either allele of the fathers genotype. The same for Allele 2.

I tried using regexpr as follows, in R:

```
vcf_GT$MVLR <- regexpr(c(sapply(strsplit(as.character(vcf_GT[,10]),"/"),function(x) x[1])), 
(sapply(strsplit(as.character(vcf_GT[,10]),"/"),function(x) x[2])), 
(c(c(sapply(strsplit(as.character(vcf_GT[,9]),"/"),function(x) x[1])), 
(sapply(strsplit(as.character(vcf_GT[,9]),"/"),function(x) x[2])),
c(sapply(strsplit(as.character(vcf_GT[,8]),"/"),function(x) x[1])), 
(sapply(strsplit(as.character(vcf_GT[,8]),"/"),function(x) x[2]))))) > 0
```

with the column 10 representing the Child's genotype, and 9 and 8 representing the mothers and father's respectively.  This is tedious and I've probably forgotten a parenthesis somewhere in here.

There has to be an easier way to check child's genotype with mother and fathers.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. If I'm not making sense - I'll try to add some more detail.

Edit:  Although my code is actually one huge line, as requested I've added returns so its easier to read (though, its kind of hard to regardless :))

Comment: I'd  encourage you to use spaces and carriage returns in your code.  it makes it readable for us and debugable for you!

Comment: And post some input data with the desired output would be good too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is simply to look at the alleles that match either the mother or the father, you do not necessarily need regexp to be able to do this. You can do this with the `%in%` operator (this is also known as the `match()` function, but I prefer this syntax.

Let's set up our data frame of genotypes. Note that the last "family" is one where the child has a different allele from the mother.

```
x <- data.frame(list(mom = c("A/G", "C/C", "C/A"), 
                     dad = c("G/A", "T/T", "A/A"), 
                     child = c("G/G", "T/T", "A/T")
                    ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now, we can set up our function to check the alleles of the child. You will have to change the `c(1,2,3)` to `c(8,9,10)` for it to work on your data set, but it should work. This is the function we will use on each row of your data frame. It will split all of the genotypes of the family, compare the child to both mother and father and then determine if the child's genotype matches either parent.

```
check_child_allele <- function(x) {
    fam <- strsplit(as.character(x[c(1, 2, 3)]), "/")
    names(fam) <- c("mom", "dad", "child")
    mom_query <- fam[["child"]] %in% fam[["mom"]]
    dad_query <- fam[["child"]] %in% fam[["dad"]]
    fam_matrix <- matrix(c(mom = mom_query, dad = dad_query), nrow = 2)
    child_match_parents <- rowSums(fam_matrix)
    child_geno <- ifelse(child_match_parents < 1, FALSE, TRUE)
    return(child_geno)
}
```

Checking the example.

```
apply(x, 1, check_child_allele)

##      [,1] [,2]  [,3]
## [1,] TRUE TRUE  TRUE
## [2,] TRUE TRUE FALSE
```

Changing the data frame to represent a child that matches neither of the parents.

```
y <- x
y[2, 3] <- "A/G"  # Adding a child that has no alleles in common with parents
apply(y, 1, check_child_allele)

##      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
## [1,] TRUE FALSE  TRUE
## [2,] TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

A side note that might not be relevant to your work:

One thing that you might be concerned about is the fact that this will check if the allele is present in either parent, but it will not check if both of the parents are indeed possible parents. The second set of genotypes in the first data frame is an example since the child is "T/T", but the mother is "C/C".

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks so much - this solution works better for me. I did eventually think of the fact that this will not actually check if the parents are the correct parents - but is there a way to work that out?

Comment: There is. If you notice in the function, `fam_matrix` will be a matrix of T/F values where the rows are the alleles of the child and the columns are the challenge against the parents (mom and dad respectively).

If you add `parents_match_child <- colSums(fam_matrix)` in there, that will give you values of whether or not the parents match the child. 

You would use that to create a double `ifelse` statement: 

`child_geno <- ifelse(parents_match_child < 1, FALSE, ifelse(child_match_parents < 1, FALSE, TRUE))`

Answer (score 1):

First off, if you find yourself doing the same thing over and over, write a function.  So instead of

```
c(sapply(strsplit(as.character(vcf_GT[,10]),"/"),function(x) x[1]))...
```

Write a little wrapper:

```
myfun <- function(var1, var2, dat=vcf_GT) {
    sapply(strsplit(as.character(dat[,var1], '/'),
           function(x) x[var2])
}
```

Now the stuff you pasted above becomes something like:

```
regexpr(c(myfun(10, 1),
          myfun(10, 2)...
```

However, I think there is an easier way...

To solve a problem like this (or of any kind) I generally break it into chunks.  Start with a single "row" like you've given and write some functions that do what you want (sorry if I've gotten this wrong, but that was confusing code!)...

```
dad = 'A/G'
mom = 'G/A'
kid = 'G/G'

splt <- function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, '/'))
comp <- function(x, y) c(x[1] %in% y, x[2] %in% y)

comp(splt(kid), splt(dad))
```

From there you are an `apply` away from doing this on a data.frame:

```
## make some data
possible <- expand.grid(c('C', 'T', 'A', 'G'),
                        c('C', 'T', 'A', 'G'))

gen <- function(n, pos=possible) {
    res=possible[sample(1:nrow(possible), n, replace=TRUE),]
    return (paste(res[,1], res[,2], sep='/'))
}

n <- 10
dat <- data.frame(mom=gen(n), dad=gen(n), kid=gen(n))

# put both functions together
splt_and_comp <- function(x, y) {
    x <- splt(x)
    y <- splt(y)

    comp(x, y)
}

# you could do this with `apply` as well...
mapply(splt_and_comp, dat$kid, dat$mom)
```

---

FWIW, your current code is calling `regexpr` with three arguments as follow.  It very well could function but is impossible to read and has extra parentheses all over:

```
first_arg <- c(sapply(strsplit(as.character(vcf_GT[,10]), "/"),
                      function(x) x[1]))

second_arg <- (sapply(strsplit(as.character(vcf_GT[, 10]), "/"),
                      function(x) x[2]))

third_arg <- (c(c(sapply(strsplit(as.character(vcf_GT[,9]),"/"),
                           function(x) x[1])), 
                  (sapply(strsplit(as.character(vcf_GT[,9]),"/"),
                          function(x) x[2])),
                  c(sapply(strsplit(as.character(vcf_GT[,8]),"/"),
                           function(x) x[1])), 
                  (sapply(strsplit(as.character(vcf_GT[,8]),"/"),
                          function(x) x[2]))))
```

Comment: Thanks!  Let me have a crack at this and let you know.  Hopefully this can give me a better idea what I want as the desired output.  I've actually confused myself in the meantime...