# How to find homozygous recessive values

Tags: r, bioinformatics

Stemming from an earlier question I had about trying to check whether a parent is the correct parent given the child's genotype (see [Checking whether a "string" expression in a specified variable is contained in several other variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729152/checking-whether-a-string-expression-in-a-specified-variable-is-contained-in-s))

Now, I'm trying to see whether if the genotype of the child is a recessive genotype (having two of the same recessive values [alleles] for this gene).  In this case, the child is always affected with the disease while the parents are not (the child is a proband).  I have tried to figure out whether the parents and the child are homozygous, and kinda worked out whether the child matches the parent's genotype.... but from these two pieces of information I can't seem to to work out whether the child is homozygous recessive...

Here is what I have so far (following the [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729152/checking-whether-a-string-expression-in-a-specified-variable-is-contained-in-s) from above):

```
homo <- read.table("/.../Family1a/Family1a_vcf.txt", sep="\t", header=T)

d <- data.frame(list(mom = homo[c(1)], 
                 dad = homo[c(2)], 
                 child = homo[c(3)]
                ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


check_homo <- function(x) {
    #homo
    m1 <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(d[,2]),"/"),function(x) x[1])
    m2 <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(d[,2]),"/"),function(x) x[2])
    d1 <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(d[,1]),"/"),function(x) x[1])
    d2 <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(d[,1]),"/"),function(x) x[2])
    c1 <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(d[,3]),"/"),function(x) x[1])
    c2 <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(d[,3]),"/"),function(x) x[2])

    mom_homo <- m1 == m2
    dad_homo <- d1 == d2
    child_homo <- c1 == c2

    homo_matrix_d <- matrix(c(dad_homo,child_homo), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
    homo_matrix_m <- matrix(c(mom_homo,child_homo), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)

    homo_match_dc <- rowSums(homo_matrix_d)
    homo_match_mc <- rowSums(homo_matrix_m)

    #which ones equal parents
    fam <- strsplit(as.character(d[c(1, 2, 3)]), "/")
    names(fam) <- c("mom", "dad", "child")   
    mom_query <- fam[["child"]] == fam[["mom"]]
    dad_query <- fam[["child"]] == fam[["dad"]]
    fam_matrix <- matrix(c(mom=mom_query, dad=dad_query), nrow=2)           
    child_match_parents <- rowSums(fam_matrix)

#if child doesn't match parents and child_homo = recessive
#if child does equal parents,if homo_parent and homo_child then child = dominant

    child_rec <- ifelse((child_match_parents < 1 & child_homo == "TRUE"), "RECESSIVE", "OTHER")
    child_dom <- ifelse((child_match_parents != 0  & child_homo == "TRUE") & (mom_homo == "TRUE" | dad_homo == "TRUE"), "DOMINANT", "OTHER")

}

child_recessive_tmp <- data.frame(apply(x, 1, check_homo))
```

It is the last two lines in the loop that aren't working.  This whole thing could be wrong so I don't mind the frustrated responses.  All in all, I want one variable saying whether the child's genotype is homozygous recessive or not.

Edit:

Example of data: There is one SNP per row.

```
    Mom  Dad  Child
rs1 A/A  G/G  A/G
rs2 T/C  T/C  T/T
rs3 A/A  C/A  A/A
.
.
.
rs100 G/C A/G  C/A
```

Comment: Can you please add some example data?

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but you don't need quotes around `TRUE` and `FALSE`. In fact, you don't need the `== TRUE` at all, `& child_homo` is equivalent to `& child_homo == TRUE` (as long as `child_homo` is a boolean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code: your function returns nothing, so regardless of whether it does what you want, you will not have any output (I would suggest you use `if()` `else if()` and `else` as below).

Also: although you `apply` your function to a data frame, the function does not seem to use the input whatsoever. The first few lines operate on the original data frame -- not the input.

and I would *highly recommend* that you learn how to use `debug` to step through a malfunctioning function.

Here is a more succinct way to implement your function:

```
sample_dat <- data.frame(mom = c("A/A", "T/C", "A/A", "G/C"), dad = c("G/G", "T/C", "C/A", "A/G"), child = c("A/G", "T/T", "A/A", "C/A"))

check_homo <- function(d) {
    fam <- sapply(d, function(.) strsplit(as.character(.), "/"))
    homozygous <- unlist(lapply(fam, function(x) identical(x[[1]], x[[2]]) ) )
    if (homozygous[3] & !duplicated(fam)[3]) "RECESSIVE"
    else if (sum(homozygous[1:2]) >= 1 & homozygous[3] & duplicated(fam)[3]) "DOMINANT"
    else "OTHER" 
    }

apply(sample_dat, 1, check_homo)

# [1] "OTHER"     "RECESSIVE" "DOMINANT"  "OTHER"
```

You might use `debug` to step through `check_homo`, to understand the purpose of each line.